# Регулярные выражения и кодировки в питоне

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Вопросов два:

1) Есть текст из файла на русском языке в кодировке utf8. Я могу вывести его в консоль. print text.decode('utf8') он отображается нормально. После этого я ищу что-то в тексте и найденный текст уже не отображается нормально, там крокозябры.

```
mask = '.' characters =
re.findall(mask, text) for character
in characters: print
character.decode('utf8')
```

2) Нужно составить регулярное выражение по замене заглавных русских букв в начале предложения на маленькие. Я пока не могу даже маску составить:

```
mask =
'(^\s*[А-Я][а-я]*)|([\.\?\!]\s*[А-Я][а-я]*)'
```

Comment: Для начала дайте точную формулировку: что такое "начало предложения".

Comment: Да, извиняюсь. Самый первый заглавный русский символ. А дальше, любой заглавный русский символ, после точки / восклицательного / вопросительного знака отделенного от символа пробелом.

Comment: Но правда пострадают аббревиатуры. Не знаю пока, что с этим делать

Comment: "любой заглавный русский символ, после точки / восклицательного / вопросительного знака отделенного от символа пробелом"


OK. Напишите регексп для этого условия. Протестируйте ( да не методом тыка, а головой, или хотя бы на regex101.com ). Результаты покажите :)